# Re-create table with Entity Framework 5 and nuget

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Code First to create a table.

I created the class, the mapping file and issued the add-migration command in nuget and then the update-database command

I then changed the class and like an idiot deleted the table.

I deleted the migration class file

I issued a add-migration command

When I issue the update-database command I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the
>   object "dbo.CorrectiveActionPlan" because it does not exist or you do
>   not have permissions.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction
>   transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction
>   transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationStatements)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String
>   migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, Boolean
>   downgrading, Boolean auto)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration
>   migration, DbMigration lastMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   ClientConnectionId:a6e92a35-cc9e-4867-97a5-0a274081d853 Cannot find
>   the object "dbo.CorrectiveActionPlan" because it does not exist or you
>   do not have permissions.

How do I force EF to recreate the table?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found my answer.

I deleted the row in [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] that corresponded to my Migration

I then deleted the new migration file

I re-ran add-migration

and then re-ran update-database -verbose

Comment: You saved me serious time!

Comment: You saved me serious time too!  :))

Comment: You are the king of the jungle!

Comment: In my case it only worked after I dropped that table, but thanks for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: handy link to the topic at hand - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: I want to salute you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options I keep in my arsenal for **code-first migrations** and they depend on why you need to delete tables or delete the records. Here is my methods:

- If you modified the models and the mappings are causing an error that prevents you from not being able to update the tables you could **Delete the entire database using SQL Management Server Studio & Delete the Migration folder** You may want to save a script to re-populate your test data using an sql script or save your Configuration.cs file and when you execute the update database command the data will be re-populated.

  Here is an example of script for a stored procedure to just drop table data:

  ```
  USE [DatabaseName]
  GO
  SET ANSI_NULLS ON
  GO
  SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
  GO
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DeleteAllYardPenaltyRecords]
  AS
  EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
  EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER ALL'
  EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
  EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
  EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? ENABLE TRIGGER ALL'
  EXEC sp_MSFOREACHTABLE 'SELECT * FROM ?'
  ```
- If you just want to drop the data you can use the package manager console command: `PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration $InitialDatabase` & delete the migration file created ie: '201502210525393_example_with_error.cs' and re-run 'Add-Migration new_example.cs' again. This puts the database back to its **initial snapshot**
- Or you could use your method: delete the row in `[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]` & migration file ie: '201502210525393_example_with_error.cs' then re-run `add-migration` and `update-database`

Answer (score -1):

You could just drop the database then from the package manager console run the 'update-database' command, all would be recreated including whatever updates you made.

Comment: Unless it had data in it that is needed.

Comment: @Eric: True, but I was offering a direct answer to his question (How do I force EF to recreate the table?) - key word there being "recreate"

Comment: Yep, but not everyone who comes here has the exact same situation as the OP. Just added that caveat for others that find the answer (also, not my downvote).