# While execuing "update-database" using Packagemanager i am getting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first

While executing the "update-database" in package manager console i am getting this kind of error.

i am using MVC4 with Code-first

[First time i am executing  this comment the table is created based on model.After that i deleted one property from the model so i deleted the "UserProducts" table.and again i run the application that time i got this error.
please help me to find the problem.]

"Cannot find the object "dbo.UserProducts" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Comment: This link may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392634/re-create-table-with-entity-framework-5-and-nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your first time creating the database using package manager, you need to add/create a migration before updating the database. Or, you may be missing a migration file.

Try this:

```
//First create a migration
PM> add-migration give_it_a_name

//Then update the database
PM> update-database
```