# Cannot find the object "dbo.Table" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

I was having some issues with my Table model when trying to Update-Database, so I decided to just delete the table and start from scratch. To do this, I removed the table through Visual Studio's Server Explorer. But now when I try to Update-Database again with a new version of the Table model, I get the error "Cannot find the object "dbo.Table" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

How do I fix this? I have the model, but I can't get the SQL table to generate.

Answer (score 16):

**If you rename table during migration**, double check that order of rename is correct :

```
DropForeignKey("dbo.PartnerTransactions", "partnerID", "dbo.Partners");
RenameTable(name: "dbo.PartnerTransactions", newName: PaymentTransactions");
```

not correct  :

```
RenameTable(name: "dbo.PartnerTransactions", newName: PaymentTransactions");
DropForeignKey("dbo.PartnerTransactions", "partnerID", "dbo.Partners");
```

And etc! Rename should go after all drops and old_table_name manipulations. Sometimes EF is a slowpoke.

Comment: was looking for ages trying to work this out. Thanks :)

Comment: @ShashankKuchibhotla, using db migration class, please read any article related db migrations through entity framework

Answer (score 5):

[This answer helped me and many others.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13392874) If it doesn't work to just remove the __Migrations-table, try to remove all tables in the DB, and do an update-database -force

Comment: may be better reinstall windows or change country?

Comment: Depending on the size of the database, definitely.

Comment: Maybe better set the machine on fire.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the code inside the Up method and down method. then run the command Update-database

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        //Delete the code
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
         //Delete the code
    }
```

then it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tick the check box on the table list that you need to add  on the Update wizard
Also make sure double check the Pluralized words.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your migration, for example if the error when create table abc, check in the migration what the migration have create table or not ?

i found my problem about this, when i check my migration, the migration can't create table. so, i edit manually for create table look at the another migration file. and run again dotnet ef database update, and solved the issue.

hope this help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be a hack and may not be recommended. I had the same problem but in my case, I deleted my table using SQL server. When I was trying to do `Update-Database`, I got the same error. I followed these steps,

- I just managed to recreate a table in the SQL server with the same table name that shows up in the error message with some dummy rows.
- Then again I did `Update-Database` in the Visual Studio and the update was successful.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I defined the schema for the table names in the model entity using the table attribute. So the solution was to specify the table schema in the autogenerated migration.

```
migrationBuilder.DropTable(
    name: "TableName",
    schema: "MyCustomSchema"
);
```